# swift で imageView の丸みをつけたいがエラーが発生する　→ Instance member ’’

Tags: swift

imageViewを角丸にできないのでどなたかご教授いただけたら幸いです。

Instance member 'userImage' cannot be used on type 'UserListViewControllerCell'

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: override class func になっていて、classが間違いでした。すみません、お騒がせいたしました

Comment: 解決した場合にはコメント欄で終わらせず、ぜひ個別の回答として投稿してみてください。